# scrollreveal.js and flexbox

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, scrollreveal.js

I'm experiencing an issue with using scrollreveal.js together with flexbox.

I've created a few two-column rows along the page using display flex and when trying to reveal each column separately with the `scrollreveal` reference only one of them are working.

Any workaround while still being able to maintain the flex attributes?

HTML

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column __50 __reveal">one</div>
  <div class="column __50 __reveal">two</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.grid {
  display: flex;
}

.column.__50 {
  width: 50%;
}
```

JS

```
window.sr = ScrollReveal({
  distance: '30px',
  duration: 1000,
  scale: 0
});
sr.reveal('.__reveal');
```

Comment: The get a proper answer, post a working code snippet reproducing the issue you describe.

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem based on the example you posted.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you clearly:

1. Given- the existing code
2. When- page is scrolled
3. Then- Columns should scroll into view

I've provided a snippet that shows that it does work based on your code but you have to give enough space for the scrollreveal effect to take place.

TO TEST

Add a div that takes up the space from the initial view.

Add a height to the `.column.__50` class so you can see it in action.

Add a border so you can see how they are placed, you can always comment the border out after you no longer need it. Good practice for 'debugging' and visualizing your divs.

```js
window.sr = ScrollReveal({
        distance: '30px',
        duration: 1000,
        scale: 0
    });
    sr.reveal('.__reveal');
```

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
}
.column.__50 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 800px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/scrollReveal.js/4.0.0-beta.25/scrollreveal.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column __50 ">
    No class="__reveal 1"
  </div>
  <div class="column __50 ">
    No class="__reveal 2"
  </div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column __50 __reveal">
    one
  </div>
  <div class="column __50 __reveal">
    two
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, You have to pass a sequence interval (in milliseconds) to the reveal() method, making sequenced animations a breeze.

```
sr.reveal('.__reveal', 300);
```

> *[You can read the documentation from this reference link](https://github.com/jlmakes/scrollreveal#31-sequenced-animations)*

***Stack Snippet***

```js
window.sr = ScrollReveal({
  distance: '30px',
  duration: 1000,
  scale: 0
});
sr.reveal('.__reveal', 300);
```

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  font: 13px Verdana;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column.__50 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  border: 8px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal/dist/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column __50 __reveal">one</div>
  <div class="column __50 __reveal">two</div>
  <div class="column __50 __reveal">three</div>
  <div class="column __50 __reveal">four</div>
</div>
```